# Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $X$ to $ ]-\infty, +\infty ]$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $X$ to $ ]-\infty, +\infty ]$ and that $x\in dom(f+g)$. Show that $\partial f(\bar{x})+\partial g(\bar{x})\subseteq \partial(f+g)(\bar{x})$.

Proof:

Let $v\in \partial f(\bar{x})$ and $w\in \partial g(\bar{x})$ Then by definition of the subdifferential we get
\begin{align*}
&f(\bar{x})+\langle v,x-\bar{x} \rangle\leq f(x)\;\;\;\;(\forall\in dom(f))\;\;(\star)\\
&g(\bar{x})+\langle w,x-\bar{x} \rangle\leq f(x)\;\;\;(\forall\in dom(g))\;\;(\star\star)
\end{align*}
Adding $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$ we have

\begin{align*}
&f(\bar{x})+g(\bar{x})+\langle v,x-\bar{x} \rangle +\langle w,x-\bar{x} \rangle \leq f(x)+g(x)\;\;\;(\forall x\in dom(f)\cap dom(g))\\
&\iff (f+g)(\bar{x})+\langle v+w,x-\bar{x} \rangle\leq (f+g)(x)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(\forall x\in dom(f)\cap dom(g))
\end{align*}

Hence, $\partial f(\bar{x})+\partial g(\bar{x})\subseteq \partial(f+g)(\bar{x})$.

Can someone please confirm that this proof is correct. Thank you

Comment: What is $X$? Why isn't the domain of $f+g$ the same as $X$?

Comment: Here $X$ is used analogously to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, that is not an answer. What is $\partial f(\overline x)$? You hhave omitted way too much information from this question.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you are hinting at. Please see the edited version above

Comment: Looks okay to me. $\delta f$ is the subdifferential.